# Ansible deployment to windows host behind bastion

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am currently successfully using Ansible to run tasks on hosts that are in a private subnet in AWS, which the below `group_vars` is setting up:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -W %h:%p -q ec2-user@bastionhost@example.com"'
```

This is working fine.

For Windows instances not in a private subnet the following `group_vars` works:

```
---
ansible_user: "AnsibleUser"
ansible_password: "Password"
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

Now, trying to get Ansible to deploy to a Windows server behind the bastion by just using the `ProxyCommand` won't work - which I understand.
I believe though that there is a new protocol/module I can use called psrp.

I imagine that my `group_vars` for my Windows hosts needs to change to something like this:

```
---
ansible_user: "AnsibleUser"
ansible_password: "Password"
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_connection: psrp
ansible_psrp_cert_validation: ignore
```

If I run with just the above changes against instances that are publicly available (and not trying to connect via a bastion), my task seems to work fine:

```
Using module file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_shell.ps1
<10.100.11.14> ESTABLISH PSRP CONNECTION FOR USER: Administrator ON PORT 5986 TO 10.100.11.14
PSRP: EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
```

I know there must be more changes before I can try this on a windows server behind a bastion, but ran it anyway to see what errors I get to give me clues on what to do next. Here is the result when running this on an instance behind a bastion server:

```
Using module file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/setup.ps1
<10.100.11.14> ESTABLISH PSRP CONNECTION FOR USER: Administrator ON PORT 5986 TO 10.100.11.14
The full traceback is:
.
.
.
.
ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.100.11.14', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x110bbfbd0>, 'Connection to 10.100.11.14 timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))
```

It seems like Ansible is ignoring my `group_vars` for the `ProxyCommand` - which I'm not sure if that's expected.
I'm also not sure on what the next steps are to enable Ansible to deploy to Windows servers behind a bastion.

What config am I missing?

Comment: https://gagor.pl/2016/04/use-bastion-host-with-ansible/

Comment: @error404 that document refers to deploying on linux hosts behind a bastion, as per my question - I'm trying to deploy to a Windows host

Comment: have you tried this https://www.bloggingforlogging.com/2018/10/14/windows-host-through-ssh-bastion-on-ansible/ ?

Comment: The url provided by Pouyan definitively point to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The [doc says](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters), the `ansible_ssh_common_args` setting is appended to sftp, scp, and ssh commands. So it sounds normal to me that is not taking into account when using `winrm` or `psrp` `ansible_connection`.

As explained in [the link provided by Pouyan](https://www.bloggingforlogging.com/2018/10/14/windows-host-through-ssh-bastion-on-ansible/) in the comments, `ansible_psrp_proxy` variable will be used to provide proxy information.

```
ansible_connection: psrp
ansible_psrp_proxy=socks5h://localhost:1234
```

More info on the creation of the socks proxy can be found on: https://www.bloggingforlogging.com/2018/10/14/windows-host-through-ssh-bastion-on-ansible/